# Improper Tiff image generated from RGB888 data

Tags: c, tiff, libtiff

I'm trying to convert RGB888 image data to TIFF image. But code generates improper image.
I'm reading the RGB data from text file.Here is the output image

[image: Attached the improper image]
the black region shouldn't be there it seems that code is making low RGB values to zero. 
I'm creating tiff image without alpha channel.Please help me comprehend the issue.

```
TIFF *out= TIFFOpen("new.tif", "w");

int sampleperpixel = 3;
uint32 width=320;
uint32 height=240;
unsigned char image[width*height*sampleperpixel];
int pixval;
int count=0;


FILE *ptr=fopen("data.txt","r");
if (ptr!=NULL)
    {
      while(count<width*height)
        {fscanf(ptr,"%d",&pixval);            
        *(image+count)=(unsigned char)pixval;
        count++;}
    }
printf("%d\n",count);

TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);  // set the width of the image
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);    // set the height of the image
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, sampleperpixel);   // set number of channels per pixel
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);    // set the size of the channels
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);    // set the origin of the image.
//   Some other essential fields to set that you do not have to understand for now.
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_RGB);

tsize_t linebytes = sampleperpixel * width;
unsigned char *buf = NULL; 
//if (TIFFScanlineSize(out)<linebytes)
//  buf =(unsigned char *)_TIFFmalloc(linebytes);
//else
    buf = (unsigned char *)_TIFFmalloc(TIFFScanlineSize(out));




TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, TIFFDefaultStripSize(out, width*sampleperpixel));

uint32 row ;
//Now writing image to the file one strip at a time
for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    //memcpy(buf, &image[(height-row-1)*linebytes], linebytes);    // check the index here, and figure out why not using h*linebytes
    memcpy(buf, &image[(row)*linebytes], linebytes);        
if (TIFFWriteScanline(out, buf, row, 0) < 0)
    break;
}


TIFFClose(out);

if (buf)
 _TIFFfree(buf);
```

Comment: You should try to progress one step at a time. First, what happens if you try first to fill all scanlines with harcoded values, instead of reading the data from your text file ? (for example generating an completely red tiff)

Comment: Your TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP is wrong. It needs be set to either HEIGHT or a fractional division of HEIGHT. The rest looks ok. Post the actual file and I can tell you more precisely where it's going wrong.

Comment: @BitBank Could be you please be more specific about the files as this is the complete code. Apart from this there is only data file. Thanks

Comment: Post the TIFF file so I can inspect it, not a PNG image of the TIFF file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4CW5GKV8jUueHlrenFlaVZsSk0/edit?usp=sharing ---- this the link , i have uploaded on goolge drive

Comment: Thanks for posting the image. The improper ROWSPERSTRIP value is ignored by most viewers (including mine). The real problem is that you only generated 1/3 of the necessary data. Somewhere upstream you're not copying or generating the full data size. Maybe you're doing a memcpy(dest, src, width*height) instead of width*height*3.

Answer (score 0):

I found your example at [this tutorial](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/638-f1999/libtiff_tutorial.htm). Since you are not the original author, you should always post a link to help others and avoid plagiarism.

The example works great except the part you added. To read file into byte array, use this instead (after you read what [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) does):

```
fread(image, 1, sizeof image, ptr);
```

in your original code, you omitted `sampleperpixel`

```
while(count<width*height*sampleperpixel) ...
```

so you read only one third of the image.